# Running a thread more than once

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread which runs my game loop. I want to be able to run this game loop each time I start a new game. But since the threads in Java can only be started once, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `Thread` around the same `Runnable` instance and start that.

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason the thread runs only once, then stops. I invoke new Thread(new GameLoop()).start() when I start the game. Why isn't this working? (It works fine on the first try though)

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid. When I start the game again, I forgot to reset the enemy position so when I start it the enemy is on my character so I die immediately. That method works after all. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenC I don't know, but it works so it doesn't matter I guess :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the Thread that runs the game loop to keep running it, you need to code it something like this:

```
  public class GameLoop implements Runnable {
      ...
      public void run() {
         while (gameNotFinished) {
            // do stuff
         }
      }
  }
```

If that is not working, then the chances are that the `run()` method is dying because of an exception that you are not catching / logging, and therefore not noticing.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** When you say that `"you need to run a thread"`, i means **you want to start a sub-task on a separate thread.**

**2.** Now if you mean this **certain sub-task**, then please **prefer to run a** `new thread`.

**3.** As you said `But since the threads in Java can only be started once`

This means that when a `thread (thread of execution)` **completes its** `run()` method, then the Thread object associated with it permanently looses its threadness, right....

But if this thread is **from a pool**, then the **pool itself manages the Thread objects and its reused**. Try using `Executors` from `java.util.concurrent` package.

Answer (score 0):

1) The short answer is precisely what SLaks already said: just "...create a new thread around the same runnable instance and start that."

2) I think you might be confused about the distinction between the everyday meaning of "start", and the semantics of the Java Thread method "start()".  This tutorial might help:

- http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/threads/states.html

3) Should you wish to re-use the *same* thread, you can use the methods "wait()" and "resume()":

- http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial